# How to do the "wavy" vocal sequence like an opera singer?

Tags: voice

How do you do the "wavy" vocal sequence like an opera singer? You know, it's like a-h-a-h-a. I'm not sure how to describe it, but it's kinda like when an opera singer or a singer in general, such as Celine Dion or Britney Houston, makes a long "wavy" vocal sequence, especially at the end of a verse.

Comment: Can you give a link to a representative example?

Answer (score 2):

You might be disappointed in this answer, because it's nothing special! Based on the [link](https://youtu.be/7KBQLgeKRbg?t=249) you gave in a comment, this is just something called a **melisma**, which is just a string of pitches sung on a single syllable.

Think about singing a children's song or a hymn; most new syllables are a change of pitch or a re-articulation of the current pitch. (Think "Old McDonald," "Itsy-Bitsy Spider," etc.) Occasionally you'll sing a string of pitches on one syllable, but it's relatively rare.

With a melisma, however, it's one syllable for a string of several pitches, which is all Celine Dion is doing in your example.

Although occasionally a vocalist may switch between an "ah" and an "oh," I'd say this still falls neatly within the melisma tradition.

There's no specific technique to it; just sing it well!

Comment: Nothing special? I don't have the faintest idea how to do that! And it sounds great so I wanna learn how to do it.

Comment: The trick is to do it slowly, making sure you get each pitch right. Then speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You mean coloratura?  Like in the [Queen of the Night aria](https://youtu.be/F9ijwfRTv0o?t=37)?  Well, you do that by having good teachers and practising a whole lot until you have a solid voice support and solid control over it and solid pitch and solid delivery and good breath elasticity and well-rounded leggiero.  There is no particular trick to it.  You just do everything right and well-controlled and coordinated and it will sound ok on a practised voice.

Comment: Yeah, kinda like that, but maybe less "sharp". https://youtu.be/7KBQLgeKRbg?t=249 Notice the "wavy" o-o-o-o-n-n-n part at the end. Something like that. I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to use a link to a video here cuz of the copyright stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking about vibrato? Sometimes singers will increase the vibrato at the end of a phrase for dramatic effect.